# Is there a better way to hide & store read only data for a JQuery/JavaScript app than putting it in PHP arrays?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am making a mostly client side JavaScript / JQuery app that processes data I store on the server. I do not want this data easily scrape-able by bots, so right now I am storing all of the read-only data inside PHP files that the app gets via JSON and parses on the client side. I decided to do this instead of a MySQL database because I will never need to update the data (and I assumed - perhaps incorrectly - that it would be much easier for the web server to spit out JSON than query a database).

I know this isn't 100% secure, but I thought it would be better than keeping the data in an easily readable javascript or json file.

Is there a better way I can store data on my server so it can only be read when the app needs it, or make it harder to scrape?

Cheers,

Comment: Would attaching the data to dom nodes, via jQuery's data function be of any use?  `$("#myDiv").data("salePrice", 19.99);` - I dont think that would be scrapable, since it never shows up on the dom.

Comment: Basically the rule of thumb is. If you use it on the client side it is public. period :)

Comment: @Adam Rackis - the data is actually an array of arrays, so I do not think that would work

Comment: @PeeHaa - true :) I just want to make it as hard as possible. So if someone takes the time to go through my app and view every possible combination, they deserve the data anyway. I just don't want it as easy as "view source"

Comment: And you're avoiding using a database because...?

Comment: @Kenaniah I just thought it would be faster to have the files in php then get parsed by the browser... but I think you might be right. The easiest solution could be a database.

Comment: Definitely use a DB. Multiple PHP files to store data versus one dynamic script accessing a DB violates the Don't Repeat Yourself philosophy. You'll start crying the minute you need to change something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it so that they have to log in in order to access the data, then you can pull what you need from the database when you need it using AJAX and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a webservice that spits out the data they can bypass the app completely by calling the webservice directly, assuming that no session authorization takes place. You'd be making it even easier to 'steal' your data.

Comment: This is a comment as it doesn't provide any solutions.